# Avoiding equal and ampersand conversion in PHP

Tags: php, special-characters, codeigniter-3

I have a php variable containing some special characters, inside a *Codeigniter 3 controller*:

```
page_url = 'search=' . $expression . '&page';
```

In a template, I use this variable:

```
<a href="<?php echo $page_url; ?>"></a>
```

In the in the browser I see the characters mentioned above in this form:

```
posts/search?search%3Dharum%26page=2
```

The `=` sign turns to `%3D`, "&" to `%26`.

I tried `page_url = urldecode($page_url);` but it does not work.

How do I keep the **original** characters?

Comment: i wasn't able to produce this issue. you need to var_dump or may be log the $page_url to see what it is before echoing. for me it didn't convert any special chars in my url

Comment: @kenzotenma `var_dump($query_string_segment);` returns string(17) `"search=harum&page"`. The variable is inside a Codeigniter 3 controller.

Comment: rawurldecode Returns a string in which the sequences with percent (%) signs followed by two hex digits have been replaced with literal characters. Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php

Comment: _“In the in the browser I see the characters mentioned above in this form”_ - where is `posts/search?` supposed to come from, when you only echo out `search=harum&page` …?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use utf8 decode and try again

```
echo utf8_decode(urldecode("search%3Dharum%26page=2"));
```

Try this decode function.

```
function decode($url)
{
    $special = array(
        '%21' => '!', '\\' => '%5C', // so on you need to define.
    );

    foreach($special as $key => $value)
    {
        $result = str_replace($key, $value, $url);
    }

    return $result;
}

echo decode("search=%21");
```

Comment: Same result, no change.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not that easy to reproduce. The following rextester demo produces the text in the form you request, using basically your code: http://rextester.com/YTY13099

```
<?php
$page=2;
$expression='harum';

$page_url = 'posts/search?search=' . $expression . '&page=' . $page;

?>

<a href="<?php echo $page_url; ?>"></a>
```

resulting in

```
<a href="posts/search?search=harum&page=2">Link</a>
```

Could it be that the problem is caused by that fact that the script is part of a codeigniter controller? I do not know anything about codeigniter but I can image that further processing takes place there.